# Unity проблема в анимации

Tags: c#, unity3d

Проблема по всей видимости в анимации, потому что размер правильно изменяется для поворота, но поворот странный, вообще не понимаю, что такое

ссылка на видео проблемы [видео](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYXtZ.jpg)

Comment: А как должно быть? Дополните вопрос

Comment: Должно чтоб было как в начале видео , что он смотрит вправо и бежит вправо , когда смотрит влево , бежит влево